# ¿En que parte poner el tiempo de ejecución del popover?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Este es un tooltip que lo uso para que al pasar el cursor por encima de algún nombre de usuario, me trae los datos de la BD y se llena con los datos del usuario que he pasado el cursor.
Tengo un problemita con este codigo.El funciona bastante bien,pero lo que no encuentro la forma de ponerle un tiempo con una animación para que aparezca el tooltip.Lo que quiero es ponerle un tiempo determinado antes de que aparezca el tooltip.Osea que pasen 2 o 3 segundos para que se presente el tooltip.

En que parte del codigo pondria yo eso.Se que es JQuery basico.Pero no logro hacerlo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var k = jQuery.noConflict();
        k(".pop")
            .popover({ trigger: "auto" , html: true, animation:false})
            .on("mouseenter", function () {
                var _this = this;
                k(this).popover("show");
                var getuser = "getuser.php";
                var userid = k(this).attr('data-popover');
                var Userid = 'userid='+ userid  ;

                k.ajax({
                    url:getuser,
                    data:Userid,
                    type:'POST',
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        k("#jota").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i>');
                        },
                   success:function(result){
                       k(".jota").html(result);
                   }
                });

                k(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                    k(_this).popover('hide');
                });
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function () {
                var _this = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!k(".popover:hover").length) {
                        k(_this).popover("hide");
                    }
                }, 20);
             });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Para la animacion, deja el atributo `animation=true`:

```
k(".pop").popover({ trigger: "auto" , html: true, animation:true});
```

para el tiempo usa `delay`:

```
k(".pop").popover({ trigger: "auto" , html: true, animation:true, delay: {show: 500, hide: 100} });
```

Pero según los métodos de la documentación (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp) o usas `'show'` o usas `'options'` sino no veras los efectos de las opciones, por lo que debe ajustar tu `javascritpt` para que solo use `options`

Aqui un ejemplo, incluye `trigger:hover` para que se muestre al pasar el mouse y se oculte al retirarlo de modo que no tengas que usar `show` ni `hide`

```
$("#prueba").popover({ trigger: "hover",html: true,content:"hola mundo", animation:true,delay: {show: 500, hide: 100}})
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
            //aqui tu ajax
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function () {
            //aqui algo que quieras ejecutar al quitar el hover aunq ya no creo que sea necesario
    });
```

Fíjate que el contenido esta en el atributo `content`

Comment: genial, no sabia que se podía hacer, lo llevare a mi sistema, gracias :D

Comment: no soy el que formulo la pregunta, pase por aca a ver que le titulo me llamo la atencion.